# Python Live Video Stream Rebroadcasting

Tags: python, video

I am trying to create a webcam viewer as a present for my father-in-law (think smart picture frame that displays webcam streams). I would like to use a raspberry pi with a monitor connected. I would like to code it so that I could input URLS and it would capture/rebroadcast just the video stream. I have tried several different search terms, but the only information I can find has to do with streaming a webcam connected to the pi to the internet. I want the opposite. I need some direction on how to connect to/capture public streams. I can program and can read, but I am having trouble finding resources. I would prefer python, but can use other languages. I can figure out how to display the video and how to program the urls. What I need to figure out is how to get the stream given a URL. Any advice/direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can have a closer look on OpenCV

Comment: Can you use OpenCV to capture based on a URL? The only examples I have found dealing with OpenCV seem to be broadcasting/capturing a webcam connected to the computer.